# ERROR: (dev_appserver) Access is denied

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to follow the Google AppEngine "Hello World" example (on Windows 10), but the plumbing seems to be broken. When I execute

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

from the command prompt (as administrator) I get

> "ERROR: (dev_appserver) Access is denied: [C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\DLLs\select.pyd]"

I have confirmed that the path to dev_appserver.py is in my PATH environment variable. What else can I do?

Comment: I just discovered that the "bin" subfolder (and all others except "platform" and "rpm" have disappeared! 

I reinstalled Google SDK, ran through the whole process (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart), and it happened again!

Comment: Run the command again with the [debug log level](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command) and paste the full response